# Django Admin- Limiting ForeignKey Field's choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've been working on my Django Project.
I use custom Forms (a class called Form), and I've got a class called **Restricted_Form**. The point of this class is that an Admin user ("staff status" user") has the option restrict which users or groups can have access to the Forms/submit filled Forms:

```
#....models.py:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Restricted_Form(models.Model):
    Form = models.ForeignKey('forms.Form')
    Authorized_Users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    Authorized_Groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="restriction_owner")
```

"Form" itself has:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
#this is always the user who created it
```

My issue is limiting what the non-superuser admins can do. They should only be able to create **Restricted_Form** objects including a **Form** they have created themselves. In practice, when they create a Restricted_Form, only "Forms" that they have created themselves should appear as options to select, in the drop-down menu.
This is my related admin class right now:

```
#...admin.py
class RestrictedFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    fieldsets = [
    (None, {"fields": ("Form", "Authorized_Users", "Authorized_Groups")}),]
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'user', None) is None:  
            obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(RestrictedFormAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return True 
        return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_superuser

admin.site.register(Restricted_Form, RestrictedFormAdmin)
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class RestrictedFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        context['adminform'].form.fields['Form'].queryset = Form.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return super(RestrictedFormAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: Meanwhile I've been trying to get it working, creating a separate class with forms.ModelForm and using filter() there, but this is way cleaner and it works! Thank you very much :)